# Crash (SIGABRT) while adding a view. (WebView)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

I am having a crash (triggered by an exception) while adding a WebView. I haven't figured out why. And yes I have browsed the web because this is a very common problem though with no success, I found an answer saying that I should implement the DSYM to track the stack correctly, because looking at all those addresses is just meaningless (and I agree), the thing is I have no idea on how to do this. I found this: [save dsym files.](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/12/23/automatically-save-the-dsym-files/) But I didn't figure out how to integrate it into my project, besides it looks dangerous. And yes I have NSZombie enabled too, but to no avail.

Anyway now to the point of my question. I have a button that triggers an event, the event changes a string (the URL) according to the button pressed. Then this IBAction calls on the delegate, and the delegate makes a transition to a view that has a UIWebView that will open with the URL edited by the IBAction. So I have the following code:

This is the Delegate method:

```
WebViewController *awebViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] 
                                         initWithNibName:@"WebView" bundle:nil];
[self setWebViewController:awebViewController];
[awebViewController release];
self.webViewController.finalURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", linkString];
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
// HERE happens the crash, found out using breakpoints
[self.window addSubview:[webViewController view]];

[UIView commitAnimations];
[viewController release];
viewController = nil;
```

This is the exact crash message:

```
-[WebView initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5718320
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '[WebView initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5718320'
```

I have the theory that it tries to make the transition but that there is no actual view to add. Though that is a wild guess. Exceptions are usually called by those kinds of things but in this case I don't see what is happening.

Thank you for your help, and forgive me if it is too dumb a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a guess from my side:

Do you have a view in your nib that should be a UIWebView but you changed the Class of that view to WebView?

You should first check this in interface builder.
This exception is exactly what happens if you change the Class of a view element to a class that isn't available.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. Thank you very much, but can you explain why must I set it that way when it follows the UIWebViewDelegate anyway? Now I have a few other problems but I think I can solve them.

Comment: WebViewController might follow the UIWebViewDelegate protocol. But that doesn't turn the subclass of UIViewController into an UIView. The name is the only thing they have in common.

Answer (score 2):

The exact error is that some instance of a class called `WebView` (*not* `UIWebView`) at memory address `0x5718320` is being sent the message `-initWithCoder:`, which it doesn’t recognize. That message is called when loading views created with Interface Builder; check your nibs for a view that you’ve changed to a custom `WebView` class.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and renamed class WebView into WebViewCustom by XCode refractor/Rename feature, cleaned up project and now it works fine.